# Undesirable bar in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse very often some undesirable shortcuts pops up undesirable bars.

How can I get rid of this mystery empty bar which appeared in my Eclipse?
Picture of my problem:

[image]

Comment: The little white dash `-` on the right, no?

Comment: No, it only minimalizes all my pages with code (Console included) and create icon on the right vertical bar

Comment: Looks like some toolbar that cannot handle dark theme (it does look like you are using the dark theme). If you change the theme and use the same shorcut, you will know which toolbar it is, and then you can disable the corresponding action group

Comment: Finally only this reset of perspective helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703717/how-to-restore-default-perspective-settings-in-eclipse-ide