# How to Unhide menu bar Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

I wanted a full screen of Eclipse Oxygen in order to get good readability of code. So I hide toolbar, Status bar and I did Alt+F11, I went too far and I also hide menu bar. Now I am not able to show it back. How can I do so?

To hide menu bar I did this - Window-> Perspective-> Customize Perspective-> deselected all menu->ok

I am using Eclipse Oxygen on 64 bit Windows.

Comment: I'm not near my Oxgen version at the moment, but I'll check tomorrow. However, for my Neon version, go back to the `Customize Perspective`. There is a `Menu Visibility` tab where the various menu items should be able to be restored. Another way, is if you right-click on a perspective's icon, use the Reset option, and then restart Eclipse may work as well.

Comment: You can't open the `Customize Perspective` sub-menu if you disabled the Window menu and all its sub-menus.   I found a workaround by manually editing the `workbench.xmi`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to restore the menu like this:

1. Close Eclipse
2. From your workspace folder, navigate to subfolder: `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench`
3. Edit the file `workbench.xmi`.  It's best to use an editor which can handle XML syntax: in Windows 10, I like EditPad Lite 8.
4. Near the start of the file, you should find your perspective as an element with attributes `xsi:type=advanced:Perspective` and `elementId="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.J2EEPerspective.NNNN"`. `NNNN` here is the name of your saved perspective.
5. Hopefully the next sub-element is `persistedState` with the attribute `key="persp.hiddenItems"`.  You can edit the value of that `hiddenItems` attribute to delete all the entries which have this form: `persp.hideMenuSC:`.  They are comma-delineated.  In my copy of this, it looks the final comma should be left in place, so the last entry retained in the list ends with a comma, like this:

   ... `,persp.hideToolbarSC:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenProjectWizard,"/>`